# how to extract the pcap time field using python and I need to find the time difference between 2 frames

Tags: python, pcap

I am trying to extract the time field from the PCAP file using the python and I need to find the time difference between 2 frames in the PCAP file
thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using Scapy?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

import os
import csv
os.chdir('C:\Program Files\Wireshark')
os.system( " tshark -r C:\Users\shalini.r\OneDrive\Desktop\tick.pcap -T fields -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f -e frame.time_delta -e udp.dstport -E header=n > C:\Users\shalini.r\Documents\check1.csv")

with open('C:\Users\shalini.r\Documents\check1.csv', 'r') as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)